# python / PyCharm: access to a protected member of another object of the same class

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-highlighting, private-members, type-hinting

In a method of my class `MyHeader` i access the private property `_label` of another `MyHeader` object `new_header`:

```
class MyHeader:
    def __init__(self, label, n_elem):
        self._label = label
        self._n_elem = n_elem

    def check_header_update(self, new_header):
        # check that label is preserved
        if new_header._label != self._label:
            raise Exception("new header must have the same label")
```

In PyCharm, this results in the syntax highlighting error "**Access to a protected member _label of a class**".

I tried specifying the type of the `new_header` parameter:

```
    def check_header_update(self, new_header: MyHeader):
```

but this is not recognized, and at run-time this leads to the error "**NameError: name 'MyHeader' is not defined**".

Any idea how to access the protected member in an accepted way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to type your function would be to use [forward references](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#class-name-forward-references), and type your `check_header_update` like so. Note that I'm also adding the return type, for completeness:

```
def check_header_update(self, new_header: 'MyHeader') -> None:
```

The reason why the type needs to be a string is because when you're defining `check_header_update`, `MyHeader` hasn't been fully defined yet, so isn't something you can refer to.

However, I don't remember if this will end up fixing the problem or not. If it doesn't, then I would either:

1. Make `_label` non-private by removing that underscore
2. Make some kind of [getter method or use properties](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property) to let other people access that data

Comment: Thanks also for the pointer to the documentation. 
Also, in the context of my class it makes sense that `_label` remains private so i am glad that it works like this.

Comment: Think the better answer for the initiate would be to include an example for @property usage

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything wrong about your initial code sample. It's just that PyCharm doesn't try to guess your parameter type. Most code bases I work with have several thousands warning and even errors from IDE analyses. You can't fix them all.

Anyway, you can specify the type of the parameter through the method docstring and PyCharm won't shout the warning anymore:

```
class MyHeader:
def __init__(self, label, n_elem):
    self._label = label
    self._n_elem = n_elem

def check_header_update(self, new_header):
    """
    :type new_header: MyHeader
    """
    if new_header._label != self._label:
        raise Exception("new header must have the same label")
```

A more modern way to do this is to use type annotation :

```
def check_header_update(self, new_header : MyHeader):
    if new_header._label != self._label:
        raise Exception("new header must have the same label")
```

Though not all IDEs (or all their versions) support it yet.

You can specify complex type hints. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html for more information.