# How deal with warning "Access to protected member" in pycharm method?

Tags: python, pycharm, encapsulation

I have some class

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def _equals(self, other):
        return self._data == other._data
```

Pycharm doesn't like that I access `other._data` because it is private.

> "Access to protected member"

This doesn't make sense to me, because the access is made from within the class.

How do I write correct code here without warnings?

Comment: It's within `self`'s class, but even if it has the `_data` property there's no guarantee `other` is also an `A`. Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44658367/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So what? the warning is about the private, not about "maybe not a correct type"

Comment: Are you aware that you can override the `==` operator in Python (and that the hook for doing so is `__eq__`, not `_equals`)?

Comment: It *doesn't* say *"maybe not a correct type"*, it says you're accessing a private member. Python is duck typed, from the interpreter's point of view it doesn't matter whether `other` is an `A` as long as it has the `_data` property. My point is that this may not be access within `other`'s class.

Comment: @user2357112 my problem is actually in one of my own functions, I just named it equals for the example. maybe it is confusing and should have just been named foo()

Comment: You should check they type... If you add an `if not isinstance(other, A): return false` you wont get the warning. Maybe simply adding the `, other: A` annotation is enough...

Comment: @jonrsharpe which is why I expect it to assume _data exists for other, and I don't understand why that is relevant here. Will read the link you gave me, thanks!

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I don't understand what annotaion, could you elaborate please?

Comment: [Python3 supports type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). PyCharm should be smart enough to use them to infer the types.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta extremely cool! too bad this project is still on 2.7 Sure will use this when we migrate!

Comment: You can hint types in 2.7 with docstrings, PyCharm understands those too: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python 3.5+ answer (Type hints introduced):

```
from __future__ import annotations


class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data

    def _equals(self, other: A):
        return self._data == other._data
```

Using type hints as suggested by @Giacomo Alzetta, and allowing to type hint the class itself using `from __future__ import annotations`.

No need to hack PyCharm anymore or write ugly comments.

---

As also noted by @jonrsharpe, [python 2 also supports type hints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html) via docstrings.
I will not post this here as I support Python 2 losing support.

Comment: On the second thought, this would only work for `_equals` or the like, not generally. So, the solution you found would solve your problem only. (Not the title you wrote)

Comment: @Polv Please show code this would not work for, I am not following

Comment: not your code, but if I create `def _equivalent(self, other: B):` method, checking if different types are equivalent.

Comment: @Polv Still not following. If you define `def _equivalent(self, other: B):` just the same, it would work just the same

Answer (score 23):

If you really need it, like [namedlist](https://pypi.org/project/namedlist/)'s `._asdict()`, the answer is [Can I get PyCharm to suppress a particular warning on a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847884/can-i-get-pycharm-to-suppress-a-particular-warning-on-a-single-line):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
    def _equals(self, other):
        # noinspection PyProtectedMember
        return self._data == other._data
```

Comment: This is not an answer, I wish it weren't as widely accepted

Comment: This is an answer in the strict sense, as it does suppress the warning in Pycharm as OP requested. It just took the poor approach of silencing a very legitimate warning instead of properly writing a more robust code.

Answer (score 2):

The comments in OP's question have a *lot* of great insight about the warning, proper fixes and best practices, most were unfortunately not mentioned by the current answers. So here it goes:

About the warning itself, OP says:

> This doesn't make sense to me, because the access is made from within the class.

No, it is not. `other` can be *any* class, not necessarily `A`. So even if *you* only pass `A` instances as `other`, there's nothing *in the code* that **indicates** or **enforces** that.

*Indication* can be done with *type hints*, as explained by [Gulzar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67200849/624066).

And there are some approaches for *enforcing* this:

- Force `other`'s type to be `A` (or a subclass): `if not isinstance(other, A): return False`. This is the arguably the preferred way, but it does defeat Python's duck-typing.
- If instead of a regular method `_equals()` you're using one of the [predefined "rich comparison" special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) such as `__eq__()`, `__lt__()`, `__gt__()`, you can return a special value to give a chance to `other`'s class *reflection method* to handle the call: `if not isinstance(other, A): return NotImplemented`
- If you want to preserve duck-typing to allow unknown classes, *and you're **not** using a private attribute* such as `_data` (otherwise you'll still get the warning), you could use a `try`-block to handle a missing attribute:

```py
try:
    return self.data == other.data
except AttributeError:  # other has no .data
    return False
```

Comment: I think there is also `hasattr()`

Comment: @Polv: `hasattr()` also uses a try/except block behind the scenes, so it's usually better  (and faster) to use the EAFP pattern instead of `if hasattr(): return ... else return False`